# CSS button permanently pushed down state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a button to stay pushed down when clicked on. However, the box-shadow portion in what I'm working with, and the CSS active state part are both confusing me.

I know this is doable considering this code: http://jsfiddle.net/UEkBQ/

This is the code I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/frnYf/

It seems that the CSS "#button:active" is constantly functional, while I only want it to be toggled when clicked on.

Comment: The example you list as being doable uses a class to style it, not the `:active` psuedo-selector. It is not possible in straight CSS using the psuedo-selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first fiddle works because `make-me-green` is a css class name, and can be targetted by css rules, where as `#button:active` is not a class name (its a css selector consisting of a tag id and a pseudoclass).

Change your css rule from `#button:active` to `#button.some-css-class-name` and the js to `$(this).toggleClass('some-css-class-name');`

The reason you need `#button.some-css-class-name` and not just `.sone-css-class-name` is that `#` selectors have a higher priority than `.` selectors.

In response to your question about the `.`...

```
<div id="blah" class="blah">hello</div>
```

we can target this div with its class or its id, to tell css which we use a `.` for a class or `#` for an id.

Or try: http://jsfiddle.net/frnYf/35/

Comment: I've already switching the rule into a class and with no luck. The id #button needs to be included with :active in order to function. Not exactly sure how they work together.

Comment: That worked perfectly! But why is it that `$(this).toggleClass('some-css-class-name');` doesn't require a "." before the class name?

Comment: @Tony: Because it is only the name of the class, and `.some-css-class-name` is a selector for elements with `some-css-class-name` class. To sum up: `.toggleClass()` expects **class name**, where `jQuery()` (or `$()`) expects **selector** (which starts with "`.`" for classes). That is the difference.

Comment: @Tadeck Thanks for the feedback. It's greatly appreciated! And now I know.